# Save NLTK tagger output to a CSV file

Tags: python, csv, nltk

I'm trying to analyze a text to find all the 'NN' and 'nnp', so far the code works well, but when I save the output to a CSV file I haven't been able to get the format I want. which is have the  - Word, Tag, Question Analyzed-

this is the code:

```
training_set = []

text = 'I want to analized this text'
tokenized = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
tagged = nltk.pos_tag(tokenized)
result= [(word, tag) for word, tag in tagged if tag in ('NN', 'NNP')]

for i in result:
    training_set.append(i)
    training_set.append([text])
    print(training_set)

listFile2 = open('sample.csv', 'w', newline='')
writer2 = csv.writer(listFile2,quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, lineterminator='\n', delimiter=',')
for item in training_set:
    writer2.writerow(item)
```

The outcome is the following:

[image]

Any idea how can I keep all the information within the same line. like this:

[image]

I have change the code and using two lists and then use Zip to add both to the CSV file, this seems to work however, all close in ""  and ()

```
training_set = []
question = []


        text = 'I want to analyzed this text'
        tokenized = nltk.word_tokenize(text)
        tagged = nltk.pos_tag(tokenized)
        result= [(word, tag) for word, tag in tagged if tag in ('NN', 'NNP')]
        for i in result:
            training_set.append(i)
            question.append([text])

listFile2 = open('sample.csv', 'w', newline='')
writer2 = csv.writer(listFile2,quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, lineterminator='\n', delimiter=',')
for item in zip(training_set, question):
    writer2.writerow(item)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Please avoid writing a Python object that's not a base type to a text file. Parsing it would give you headaches later. Use pickle https://wiki.python.org/moin/UsingPickle

Comment: Thanks for the advise I will check the documentation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like this to get your data in the desired format, before writing it to csv:

```
[tag + (text,) for tag in result]
```

OUTPUT:

```
[('text', 'NN', 'I want to analyze this text')]
```

It will essentially give you a list of tuples in the format you need, which you can then write to your csv.